# Using Javascript to pop up image in new window

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, popup

I have a webpage in which an element is clicked on and an image is obtained from the server using a JQuery post function and should be displayed in a new window which is resized to the image. The relevant Javascript function is as follows (where myImage is the returned image in base 64 format).

```
function showPicture(label) {
        var newWindow = window.open("", label,"scrollbars=0, toolbar=0");
        $.post( 'picture-view', { labelname: label },
        function(myImage) {
            newWindow.document.write("<img src='data:image/png;base64," + myImage + "'/>");
            newWindow.resizeTo(newWindow.document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].width,     newWindow.document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].height+newWindow.outerHeight-newWindow.innerHeight);
            newWindow.focus(); 

        }
    );          
}
```

There are three things which are causing me problems.

1. The image is inserted into the new window with a white border which I cannot figure out how to remove.
2. The term `newWindow.outerHeight-newWindow.innerHeight` is supposed to account for the toolbar etc. when resizing the window, but both are being output as zero.
3. This last one has really been annoying me. If I put the line `var newWindow = window.open("", label,"scrollbars=0, toolbar=0");` within the callback function which starts on line four then the new window is created too small and will not be resized by the resizeTo function.

Any advice or directions to further reading would be very helpful.

Comment: For the border you can just add `style="border:0;"` or `border="0"` to the img tag.

Comment: have you considered an in-page [lightbox](https://www.google.com/#q=lightbox) solution?

Comment: @RTB: I thought border was deprecated?

Comment: @mdmullinmax: I've actually been trying (and failing) to do that this afternoon but thought this would be a simpler method. I do agree that Lightbox looks much more slick and may try that in the next upgrade.

Comment: @elo96 well `style="border:0;"` should work and is definetly not deprecated. Also valid html images should come with an alternate text attribute like `alt=""`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using jQuery, so you could simplify this A LOT, but since you're already using plain JS for so much, I just kept going with it.

You should wait until the image is loaded before opening the new window, that way you can set the size to the same as the image, something like this:

```
function showPicture(label) {
    $.post( 'picture-view', { labelname: label }, function(ImageSrc) {
       var myImage = new Image;
           myImage.src = "data:image/png;base64," + ImageSrc;
           myImage.style.border = 'none';
           myImage.style.outline = 'none';
           myImage.style.position = 'fixed';
           myImage.style.left = '0';
           myImage.style.top = '0';
           myImage.onload = function() {        
               var newWindow = window.open("", label,"scrollbars=0, toolbar=0, width="+myImage.width+", height="+myImage.height);
                   newWindow.document.write(myImage.outerHTML);
          }​
    });
}
```

Here's a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/GEfsW/) showing how it's done, with the base64 just added in the file as I did'nt have time to create some sort of fake Ajax function.

Comment: Thank you, that works perfectly. Could I check my understanding of 'onload'? Would I be right in thinking that when the line 'myImage.src=...' is encountered the image is retrieved from the server and onload is called when this retrieval is complete?

Comment: Nope, not really in this case as the image is in code (base64). The code is retrieved in the `$.post` function, but to get the correct dimensions the image needs to be loaded in the browser. When using javascripts `new Image`, the image is actually loaded in the browser regardless of it being visible or not, and the onload function executes when the image has finished loaded in the browser, and then you can use the actual dimensions of the image. Before the image is loaded, width and height will in most cases return nothing or the wrong values.

Answer (score 0):

You can reference the image in the new window this way:

```
var img = $("img",newWindow.document)[0]; // Get my img elem
```

Adapting to your code:

```
function showPicture(label) {
    var newWindow = window.open("", label,"scrollbars=0, toolbar=0");
    $.post( 'picture-view', { labelname: label },
    function(myImage) {
        newWindow.document.write("<body marginheight='0' marginwidth='0'><img src='data:image/png;base64," + myImage + "'/></body>");
        var img = $("img",newWindow.document)[0];
        newWindow.resizeTo($(img).width(), $(img).height());
        alert($(img).width()+","+$(img).height()); //Just to check values
        newWindow.focus(); 
    });          
}
```

I guess the white border is due to body margins, so I added

```
<body marginheight='0' marginwidth='0'>
```

in

newWindow.document.write

to remove them.

I tested it in Firefox and it works but sometimes it opens a smaller window, maybe beacause the resize is done before the whole of the image is loaded. In this case you can add a window.setTimeout to avoid the problem.

Comment: The smaller window problem happened to me slightly unpredictably and I agree that it is probably due to the resize being done before the image is loaded. In another answer to this question it was suggested that I use the 'onload' attribute which works very nicely.